# How could I better optimize this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Here's the query thats taking over 20 minutes.

`SELECT * FROM company WHERE Age>5 GROUP BY Network ORDER BY Network DESC  LIMIT 0,2001`

I have indexes on Age and Network. Is there a way to do run this query more efficiently? Using a server side language (php) to run multiple separate queries is an option.

Comment: Could you please specify the reason of grouping the data by `Network` column ? Why is it needed?

Comment: ...yeah, why GROUP BY Network when you're not using any grouping operations? (like COUNT(*) etc)

Comment: Have you tried running an `EXPLAIN` / `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` on your query? The output of EXPLAIN might give some hints on how some indexes are used or not.

Comment: @PeterLillevold it is a mysql-flaw to even accept such a query... MsSQL won't.

Comment: The reason for the `GROUP BY ` is there are duplicates.

Comment: What means *taking forever*? How much rows does your table have? How much columns does the table have? What exact (programing language code) command are you using to execute?

Comment: 7 million + rows. It takes over 20 minutes. I had to kill it at that point, so I don't know how long exactly.

Comment: Using PHP. There's about 30 columns.

Comment: @AakilFernandes Please show the code (PHP) you are using. With that number of records, the query should finish in a split second. - Or at least in an acceptable amount of time, depending on your server load and/or hardware.

Comment: @dognose I'm testing with a GUI (Sequel Pro). So While PHP will be used in production, it is certainly not a PHP issue.

Comment: @AakilFernandes It can't ne a mysql-Issue either. There is *nothing* critical in the query at all. So i would assume you are having an unaborted loop somewhere in the code. - What happens if you just do `SELECT * FROM company LIMIT 0, 2001` ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM company GROUP BY Network LIMIT 0,2001` also takes a long time (>1 minute). So I'm pretty sure the bottle neck is in the group by

Comment: Extend the query step by step, see what is time consuming. I recommend: "Add Where condition", "Add Order by", "Add Group by". Execute each step individually.

Comment: Then, please add a column `count(*) as count`, and see what the topmost results are returning when grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Create a composite index on `age, network, companyid` and test how long this runs:

```
SELECT network, min(companyid)
FROM company
WHERE Age > 5
GROUP BY network;
```

This should use the index and be reasonably fast.

Now, join in to get the rest of the information:

```
select c.*
from company c join
     (SELECT network, min(companyid) as mincompanyid
      FROM company
      WHERE Age > 5
      GROUP BY network
      ORDER BY network DESC
      LIMIT 0, 2001
     ) n
     ON c.companyid = n.mincompanyid;
```

This assumes `company` has a primary key called `companyid` and a composite index on `age, network, companyid`.

EDIT:

If the first query is *not* reasonably fast, then estimate the number of rows you need to get 2001 unduplicated names.  Then do:

```
select c.*
from company c join
     (SELECT network, min(companyid) as mincompanyid
      FROM (SELECT c.*
            FROM company
            WHERE Age > 5
            ORDER BY network DESC
            LIMIT 10000
           ) c
      GROUP BY network
      ORDER BY network DESC
      LIMIT 0, 2001
     ) n
     ON c.companyid = n.mincompanyid;
```

In this case, 10,000 is assumed to be big enough to get 2,001 networks.  This version should fix the performance problem.